# egrep to find largest suffix for file

Tags: regex

There are files like this:

```
Report.cfg
Report.cfg.1
Report.cfg.2
Report.cfg.3
```

I want to fetch the max suffix, if exists (i.e. 3) using egrep.
If I try simple egrep:

```
ls | egrep Report.cfg.*
```

I get the full file name and the whole list, not the suffix only.
What could be an optimized egrep?

Comment: You'll very likely need to use a programming language here.

Comment: Are all your files ending with a dot and number?

Comment: @anubhava Apart from one file, all files end with dotted number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` to find greatest number from a list of file ending with dot and a number.:

```
printf '%s\n' *.cfg.[0-9] | awk -F '.' '$NF > max{max = $NF} END{print max}'

3
```

Comment: Thanks something like this was exactly what I was looking for.